# Is it possible to extend a namespace class with same class but different path in spl_autoload_registry

Tags: php, namespaces, composer-php, autoload, spl-autoload-register

I have two namespaced classes loaded with composer with the same namespace and class. (PSR4)

```
//directory1/Foo/Bar.php
namespace Foo;

class Bar{
    ....
}
```

I have a second directory with the same namespace for overrides.

```
//directory2/Foo/Bar.php
namespace Foo;

class Bar{
    ....
}
```

Now if I register both directory1 and directory2 as auto loaders directory2 will take priority over directory1.
With this method I can completely override classes via alternate directories.

When calling new Foo\Bar;

I will get an instance of directory2/Foo/Bar.php

If the file does not exit in the second directory I will get an instance of:

I will get an instance of directory1/Foo/Bar.php

This is great but I have a problem though.

Although I can do full overrides it seems to be impossible to extend classes set up in this way.

Is it possible for Bar found in directory2/Foo to extend Bar found in directory1/Foo since they share a namespace and class name?

Answer (score 0):

I would strongly oppose the idea to let the autoloading decide which version of a class gets loaded.

If you create the same class twice, with possible differences between the two versions, any other programmer (including yourself after some time) will be confused which class really contains the correct code that is being used in your program.

Additionally, all IDEs that do a decent amount of code indexing and parsing will also get confused and signal that there are two possible classes that might be used.

Nobody will get any benefit from having exactly two different files with the exact same class name but differences in the code.

You didn't state which problem you want to get solved with this approach, but I think you should do! Autoloading should not play any role when solving object oriented programming problems.

Comment: I am implementing a theme for cakephp 3.0. The reason I want to do this is to allow themes to override controllers and cells and helpers for plugins. The controllers in cells should be rendered from the default location if no override is specified. Copying the files to the themes override directory works perfectly but it would be awesome if I was able to extend the class instead of replacing it. Because of the nature of what I am trying to accomplish it is impossible for me to rename the override class or name the original class something different. Just wanted to know if this is possible.

Comment: You just stated the topic of the real question you have. Don't ask about a technical detail about a questionable approach to solve the problem the way you want it. Ask about the more general problem you have with creating themes for CakePHP. If you add the right tags to your question, you likely will get answers from CakePHP experts that will tell you how to do it. :)

Comment: Thanks, I have had extensive conversations with the core developers of the framework on github surrounding templating and the surrounding conventions. The context of how I want to implement this is not really important, the question was one more fundamental to the nature of php and the working of the autoloaders. I knew this was likely impossible but felt it needed to be asked since I could not find any info relating to this topic after a lot of googling.